# Setting up Oracle Primary Key automatically using sequences

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

For context I'm working on a project where I want the primary Id's in my oracle database to be automatically generated from an oracle sequence. I'm using Java Server Faces and Hibernate to add items to the database.

So here's the relevant code sections:

Create Sequence Statement

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE  "BIM***********"."SEQUENCE1"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE     
    9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20  
    NOORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

Create Table Statement

```
  CREATE TABLE "BIMB2013WMMEE"."CLIENT" 
   (    "CLIENT_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CLIENT_CODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CLIENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CLIENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CLIENT_ID")
     USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
     STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
     PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
     BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
     TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
     ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
     PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
     NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
     STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
     PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
     BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
     TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "BIMB2013WMMEE"."BEFORE" 
     before insert on "BIMB2013WMMEE"."CLIENT" 
     for each row 
        begin  
          if inserting then 
           if :NEW."CLIENT_ID" is null then 
              select SEQUENCE1.nextval into :NEW."CLIENT_ID" from dual; 
           end if; 
          end if; 
         end;

        /
         ALTER TRIGGER "BIMB2013WMMEE"."BEFORE" ENABLE;
```

Here is the offending Java Code (as far as I can tell)

```
@Entity
@Table (name="client")
public class Client {

    //Fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="CLIENT_ID")
    private String id;
```

Here is the error message from Eclipse:

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Jun 06, 2016 9:19:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper     
logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
Jun 06, 2016 9:19:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper    
logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Jun 06, 2016 9:19:06 AM    
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool     [jdbc:oracle:thin:@endeavour.us.manh.com:1523/pso11r2f]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Comment: maybe your sequence has no synonym and you should define your schema in  `select my_schema.SEQUENCE1.nextval` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@SequenceGenerator` annotation on the entity and specify the `generator` attribute in `@GeneratedValue` annotation with the sequence generator name, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="client")
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence1",sequenceName="BIM***********.SEQUENCE1",
allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
public class Client {

    //Fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sequence1")
    @Column(name="CLIENT_ID")
    private String id;
```

Comment: As Hibernate assigns an id using this solution your trigger will probably be useless, unless you create clients through different applications.

Comment: @JMSilla any idea for my followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663751/using-an-oracle-sequence-with-hibernate-hbm-xml-file

Answer (score 0):

Try using @SequenceGenerator + @GeneratedValue annotations.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence1",sequenceName="BIM***********.SEQUENCE1")
@GeneratedValue(generator="sequence1")
@Column(name="CLIENT_ID")
private String id;
```